# NEST deprecated field [include]

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I just updated elastic search from 2.3.4 to 5.0.1, and nest C# nuget package to the latest 2.4.7

I have the following nest query:

```
        SourceFilter sourceFilter = new SourceFilter()
        {
            Include = Infer.Fields<Page>(p => p.Category, p => p.Title)
        };

        MultiMatchQuery multiMatchQuery = new MultiMatchQuery()
        {
            Fields = Infer.Fields<Page>(p => p.Title, p => p.MetaDescription, p => p.Keywords),
            Type = TextQueryType.PhrasePrefix,
            Query = search.Term
        };

        var searchQuery = new SearchRequest<Page>()
        {
            From = search.ResultsFrom,
            Size = search.ResultsSize,
            Source = sourceFilter,
            Query = multiMatchQuery
        };

        var searchResponse = client.Search<Page>(searchQuery);
```

I'm getting the following error back from elastic:

`Deprecated field [include] used, expected [includes] instead`

Commenting out the `SourceFilter` allows the query to run through.

Is there a different way to use `SourceFilter` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running against Elasticsearch 5.0.1, [you should use a 5.x version of NEST](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#compatibility-matrix); the latest 5.x version on nuget is [5.0.0-rc3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/5.0.0-rc3) (a prerelease) at this time, with 5.0.0 to come out very soon.

[5.x contains the `Includes` property on `ISourceFilter`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.x/src/Nest/Search/Search/SourceFiltering/SourceFilter.cs#L6-L14) that [Kulasangar highlights in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40791995/1831).

Comment: I see, I see. I didn't see that version because it's tagged as Prerelease in Nuget. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! GA release will be very soon :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `Include` should be `Includes` instead of `Include` according to [source filtering usage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/source-filtering-usage.html#source-filtering-usage). Even the error which you've mentioned above concise the incorrect syntax of `Include`. I ain't sure about the version compatibility though. If I reproduce yours, it should look something like this:

```
    Source  = new SourceFilter()
    {
      Includes = Infer.Fields<Page>(p => p.Category, p => p.Title)        
    };
```

Comment: What version of NEST library do you have? I don't see that Includes is a property of SourceFilter

Comment: @AndrewWalters sorry haven't worked with `NEST` though. Just has a look over it, [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/source-filtering-usage.html#_object_initializer_syntax_example_15) popped up. Does having includes, throwing any exception?

Comment: Ya, it looks like Includes isn't actually a field/property of the Nest library.